# how to make library of primary functions in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, javascript

I want to develop set of functions(sort of library) for CRUD in AngularJS so I can reuse them for couple of entities of my project. For server communication I made factory of $resource and using accordingly. $resource factory looks like this:

**Model File:**

```
var get_entity_model = angular.module("app.getentity", []).factory('getEntity', ['$resource', function($resource) {
        return{
            entity_view: $resource(baseurl+'/rest/'+serviceName+'/entity/:id/?app_name='+appName+'&fields=*', null, {'update': { method:'PUT' }})               
        } 
    }]);
```

And here how I'm using it in controller

**Controller File:**

```
getEntity.entity_view.get(
  function(entity_list){

  },
  function(error){

  }    
)
```

Here entity_view is the table name. I'm passing all related functions like pagination and sub request to get the data of related tables etc code I put into success function of above request.

Now I want to make a library where I can define all this stuff and simply by calling the function I should be able to get all this stuff like:

> entity.getEntity()

Should return same result as above code.

I tried with creating factory for above task but seems it need callback function and function at factory will return only data which I'm already getting from my model file so I need to make it compact and easy to use.

**Factory Code at factory file:**

```
var api = angular.module("app.entity_api", []).factory('entity_factory', ['$resource','getEntity',function($resource,getEntity) {
    var entity_factory = {};
    entity_factory.get_entity = function(callback){
        getEntity.entity_view.get().$promise.then(
                function(data){
                       callback(data.record);
                }
               );
    }
    return entity_factory;
}]);
```

And here how I call the function in controller:

**Controller code:**

```
api.controller("sample",['entity_factory','getEntity','$scope',function(entity_factory,getEntity,$scope){
    $scope.init = function(){
        entity_factory.get_entity(
            function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        );
    }
    $scope.init();  
}])
```

Problem is that my entity_factory code will return only the data from server rest of the additional code I've to do in callback function which seems not much difference than my current exercise. So, the question is how can I achieve my goal to make a library of functions with additional code which return complete compiled result to make the code reusable for other entities and compact.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data. If you want to "hard-code" some way of handling the returned data, let us know what it is. You can also use `$resource`'s approach of returning an empty array and populating it with data as they arrive.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to do CRUD operations with data, I'll need to get, post and update the data and for that will need a lib so whenever I need to get, post or update data all I need to call is simply entity.getEntity(), entity.postEntity(data), entity.updateEntity(id)

Comment: And what is the problem ? Why can't you do it this way with the code above ?

Comment: Because I've to pass callback function in controller where I'm calling the function. Please check last controller file code.

Comment: And what do you like to happen instead ? What do you want to do with the data ?

Comment: I've mentioned that in my question. I want to call it like **entity.getEntity()** in controller. In factory I should be able to return decorated data. Right now I'm qurying to multiple table to get the filtered data and also some angular code of theme for pagination and modal popup these all should covered in my lib function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57804/discussion-between-dhaval-and-expertsystem).

Comment: If you can't chat then its ok. But can you response me here?

Comment: I'm in chat too. Can you please respond?

Answer (score 0):

I like that you're a thinking of making a library but in this case, don't reinvent the wheel and save your precious time. Check out [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) and your task will be a lot easier. Restangular is an AngularJS service that simplifies common GET, POST, DELETE, and UPDATE requests with a minimum of client code. It's a perfect fit for any WebApp that consumes data from a RESTful API.